# Storing locally encrypted incremental ZFS snapshots in Amazon Glacier

Tags: linux, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, zfs

To have truly off-site and durable backups of my ZFS pool, I would like to store zfs snapshots in Amazon Glacier. The data would need to be encrypted locally, independently from Amazon, to ensure privacy. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: As of version `0.8`, ZFS On Linux supports native encryption. Perhaps the `zfs send -Rw` command is exactly what you'd want

Answer (score 12):

An existing snapshot can be sent to a S3 bucket as following:

```
zfs send -R <pool name>@<snapshot name> | gzip | gpg --no-use-agent  --no-tty --passphrase-file ./passphrase -c - | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucketname>/<filename>.zfs.gz.gpg
```

or for incremental back-ups:

```
zfs send -R -I <pool name>@<snapshot to do incremental backup from> <pool name>@<snapshot name> | gzip | gpg --no-use-agent  --no-tty --passphrase-file ./passphrase -c - | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucketname>/<filename>.zfs.gz.gpg
```

This command will take an existing snapshot, serialize it with zfs send, compress it, and encrypt it with a passphrase with gpg. The passphrase must be readable on the first line in the ./passphrase file.

**Remember to back-up your passphrase-file separately in multiple locations! - If you lose access to it, you'll never be able to get to your data again!**

This requires:

- A pre-created Amazon s3 bucket
- awscli installed (`pip install awscli`) and configured (`aws configure`).
- gpg installed

Lastly, S3 lifecycle rules can be used to transition the S3 object to glacier after a pre-set amount of time (or immediately).

---

For restoring:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname>/<filename>.zfs.gz.gpg - | gpg --no-use-agent --passphrase-file ./passphrase -d - | gunzip | sudo zfs receive <new dataset name>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `gzip -9` or `bzip2`.  Depending on the data, that might compress better. The compression won't be the bottleneck here - the network copy will.

Comment: please, fix the mistake in For restoring: section,  in s3 cp src and targert

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed now.